# Echo items with value of three

Tags: php

I need to echo all items in my column that have the value of three. If a field has the value of three I then need to echo the 'name' and 'description' on that row.

This is what I have so far

```
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{  
  echo $row['status'];
}
```

I need to write 'if $row[`status´ == 3 echo 'description' 'name' else echo 'no current staus'

I hope I made some sense because I am seriously confused

Comment: so, do you have problem with syntax or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually select the result which only has 3 value in its status

for that use this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE status='3'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(result)) {
      echo "Name: ".$row['name']."<br>Description: ".$row['description'];
}
```

and if you want to parse you result to display only those of value this then use this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(result)) {
      if($row['status']==3) {
           echo "Name: ".$row['name']."<br>Description: ".$row['description'];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if $row['status'] == 3 {
    echo ($row['description']." ".$row['name']);
}
 else
{ 
   echo ('no current staus');
}
```

The "." in the first echo means string concatenation. I'm separating description and name with a single space character, feel free to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting something more since you have the "i need to write" part that is the answer?

```
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))     // fetch_assoc better for your case
{  
   if( $row['status'] == 3 ) {
      echo $row['description'];
   }else {
      echo 'no current staus';
    }

}
```

For the sake of info for tasks with a numeric status

```
switch( $row['status'] ) {
    case 0:
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something
        break;
    case 3:
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        echo 'No status set';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{  
  if (!in_array(3, $row['status']))
  {
    echo 'no current staus';
    break;
  }

  echo $row['description'] . <br />;
  echo $row['name'] . <br />;
}
```

Comment: It workd but for every value that isn't 3 it echos 'no current status' How do I place this outside the loop so that it only shows when there are no fields with the value 3?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row['status'] == 3) {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo $row['description'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{
    if ($row['status'] == 3) {
        echo $row['name'] . ' - ' . $row['description'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'no curent status';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['status']==3) {
  echo $row['description'];
  echo $row['name'];
} else {
  echo 'no current status';
}
```

Maybe you should learn about basics of PHP and algorithms and make sure you understand this, before you move on.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use SQL to select the values for you...

```
$query1 = SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '3';

$result = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{  
  echo $row['status'];
}
```